# I'm looking to export specific access table fields to specific excel cells. My vba code isn't working

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, export-to-excel

Below is the code I'm currently am trying to use.  Basically I want to pick the fields from a table and export them to a specific cell range in excel.  When I run this code in Access I'm not getting any errors but I'm also not getting the 2nd excel temp file saved with the fields I selected in the cells I specified.  Thanks for any help.  Code below has been updated to reflect what is now working.  See below comments that helped resolve the issues I ran into.

```
Option Explicit

'Enter Location of your Template Here
Const ExcelTemplate = "C:\Users\Desktop\Export Excel\Temp.xlsx"
'Enter the Folder Directory to save results to
Const SaveResutsFldr = "C:\Users\Desktop\Export Excel\"
Sub CreateWorkbook()
Dim SaveAsStr As String
Dim ExcelApp, WB As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer

c = DCount("*", "tbldata") + 4

'Create Reference to Run Excel
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Create Reference to your Table
Dim T As Recordset
Set T = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblData")

'Loop through all Record on Table
If Not (T.BOF And T.EOF) Then
T.MoveFirst
End If
Do While Not T.EOF
'Open Your Excel Template
Set WB = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelTemplate)

For i = 5 To c
'Enter your data from your table here to the required cells
WB.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i) = T("Field1")
WB.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i) = T("field2")
WB.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D" & i) = T("field3")
WB.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E" & i) = T("field4")
'Repeat this line for each piece of data you need entered
'Changing the Sheet name, cell range, a field name as per your requirements
'WB.Wor...
'WB.Wor...

T.MoveNext
Next i
i = i + 1
Loop
'Save and Close the Workbook
SaveAsStr = SaveResutsFldr & ("Temp1") & ".xlsx"
WB.SaveAs SaveAsStr
WB.Close
Set WB = Nothing

'Move to the Next Record


'Close down the Excel Application
ExcelApp.Quit
Set ExcelApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on this line ...

```vb
Set T = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblData")
```

You can set the breakpoint by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> while the cursor is located anywhere on that line.  Or right-click on the line, then select Toggle->Breakpoint from the shortcut menu.  Either way you should see a reddish dot in the left margin next to that line.

Then run your code.  When it hits the breakpoint, Access will go into Debug (break) mode.  You can then execute one line at a time with the <kbd>F8</kbd> key, and follow the code.

You will discover the code within your `While` loop does not get executed due to the logic in the loop control ...

```vb
While Not T.BOF And T.EOF
```

That says "enter the loop if `BOF` is False and EOF is True."  When you first hit that line, you are on the first row of the recordset, so `BOF` is False, but `EOF` is also False.  So when you `AND` those 2 values, the result is False ... and Access skips over the loop.

Here is a Access Immediate window session with a recordset whose current row is the first row.

```vb
' name and value of the first field in current row ...
? rs.Fields(0).Name, rs.Fields(0).Value
id             1 
' this is the WHILE condition from your code ...
? Not rs.BOF And rs.EOF
False
```

Hope that all made sense.  If still fuzzy, just start the loop like this ...

```vb
If Not (T.BOF And T.EOF) Then
    T.MoveFirst
End If
Do While Not T.EOF
```

And end it like this ...

```vb
T.MoveNext
Loop
```

The breakpoint you set is temporary.  It does not get saved with the code.  So it will be gone if you restart Access.  If you want to get rid of it during the current session, just "toggle" it again.

Comment: This info was very helpful.  The second excel file is now being created but I'm ending up with only the last record in cells (B5:E5).  Is there a way for example to have the first records data to be in cell(B5:E5) and the next record after that to be in cells (B6:E6) and etc....

Comment: Yes, create a variable `i`.  Then `i = 5`.  And then create that range string with `"B" & i & ":E" & i`  For the next range, `i = i + 1` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the While-Condition, HTH.

> If you open a **Recordset object containing no records**, the **BOF
>   and EOF properties are set to True**, and the Recordset object's
>   RecordCount property setting is 0.

```
    If (T.EOF = True And T.BOF = True) Then
        MsgBox "Recordset object contains no records."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create Reference to Run Excel
    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

> When you open a **Recordset object that contains at least one
>   record**, the first record is the current record and the **BOF and EOF
>   properties are False** and ...

```
    While (T.BOF = False And T.EOF = False)
```

... **they remain False until you move beyond the beginning or end of the Recordset object**
        ' by using the **MovePrevious** or **MoveNext** method, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers you provided.  I've updated my original code.